# PHP - Moving multiple files with different files names to own directory

Tags: php, joomla

Hi wonder if you can help,

I'm looking to do this in PHP if someone can help me. I have a number of files that look like this:

> "2005532-JoePharnel.pdf"

and

> "1205121-HarryCollins.pdf"

Basically I want to create a PHP code that when someone ftp uploads those files to the upload folder that it will 1) Create a directory if it doesn't exist using there name 2) Move the files to the correct directory (E.g. JoePharnel to the JoePharnel Directory ignoring the number at the beginning)

I have looked through alot of code and found this code and have adapted it:

```
<?php
    $attachments = array();
    preg_match_all('/([^\[]+)\[([^\]]+)\],?/', $attachments, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
    foreach ($matches as $file) {
    $attachments[$file[1]] = $file[2];
    }
    foreach ($attachments as $file => $filename) {
            $uploaddir = "upload" . $file;
            $casenumdir = "upload/JoePharnel" . $CaseNumber;
            $newfiledir = "upload/JoePharnel" . $CaseNumber .'/'. $file;
            $each_file = $CaseNumber .'/'. $file;

   if(is_dir($casenumdir)==false){
       mkdir("$casenumdir", 0700);          // Create directory if it does not exist
    }
   if(file_exists($casenumdir.'/'.$file)==false){
        chmod ($uploaddir, 0777);
        copy($uploaddir,$newfiledir);
    }
    $allfiles = $CaseNumber .'/'. $file . "[" . $filename . "]" . ",";
    $filelistfinished = preg_replace("/,$/", "", $allfiles);
    echo $filelistfinished; 
    // displays multiple file attachments on the page correctly as: casenumber/testfile1.pdf[testfile1.pdf],casenumber/testfile2.pdf[testfile2.pdf],
```

],

}
?>

Sorry for the lack of code but best i could find.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: So you've found code from somewhere, adapted it, but what's happening? Are any errors being shown? Do you have error reporting turned on? Have you thought about using Joomla's API to manage this instead?

Comment: I am getting errors that: 1) preg_match_all() expects parameter 2 to be string, array (line 3) 2) Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (line 4). Where you said about using Joomla's API to manage this instead what do you mean by that?

Comment: `getting errors that`........?

Comment: You're using `$attachments = array();` and `$attachments` is the second argument. In regards to the Joomla API, please read the following documentation: http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_use_the_filesystem_package

Comment: Ok i then get undefined variable from moving that. And ok thanks i'll take a look at that, anything specific in the Joomla API that you can recommend that would work to solve this? Thanks

Comment: I could go and write the whole thing for you but I won't be doing all your work. My advice is read through the documentation, look at the code carefully and write each process step by step. Once done and you are still running into issues, re-post your code ;)

Comment: Be very careful with this. You are creating new files based on the file name. What happens if I upload a file called 1234-rootaccess.php.pdf ?

Comment: The documentation hasn't been done for Joomla 3.0 I fixed one error but can't yet find solution to error: PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant JPATH_COMPONENT - assumed 'JPATH_COMPONENT'. Code: <?php
//First we set up parameters
$searchpath = JPATH_COMPONENT . DS . "images";
 
//Then we create the subfolder called jpg
if ( !JFolder::create($searchpath . DS . "jpg") ) {
   //Throw error message and stop script
}

Comment: adn i'm also getting this error as well: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function jimport().......code: //Import filesystem libraries. Perhaps not necessary, but does not hurt
jimport('joomla.filesystem.folder');