# PHP - JPath Moving Multiple files to correct directory

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

See my last question as this links to it: [PHP - Moving multiple files with different files names to own directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26485435/php-moving-multiple-files-with-different-files-names-to-own-directory?noredirect=1#comment41607341_26485435)

So i decided to using the Joomla API however, the documentation was for 1.5 and 2.5 system only but i'm using 3.0. I have a number of files that look like this:

"2005532-JoePharnel.pdf"

and

"1205121-HarryCollins.pdf"

Basically I want to create a PHP code that when someone ftp uploads those files to the upload folder that it will 1) Create a directory if it doesn't exist using there name 2) Move the files to the correct directory (E.g. JoePharnel to the JoePharnel Directory ignoring the number at the beginning)

Updated: 23/10/14 - 14:05:

My new code creates the folder but won't move the file in the upload into that new folder, code is below:

```
       <?php

define( '_JEXEC', 1); 

define('JPATH', dirname(__FILE__) );

if (!defined('DS')){
    define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );


$parts = explode( DS, JPATH );  
$script_root =  implode( DS, $parts ) ;

// check path
$x = array_search ( 'administrator', $parts  );
if (!$x) exit;

$path = '';

for ($i=0; $i < $x; $i++){
    $path = $path.$parts[$i].DS; 
}
// remove last DS
$path = substr($path, 0, -1);

if (!defined('JPATH_BASE')){
    define('JPATH_BASE', $path );
}    

if (!defined('JPATH_SITE')){
    define('JPATH_SITE', $path );
}    

/* Required Files */
require_once ( JPATH_SITE . DS . 'includes' . DS . 'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_SITE . DS . 'includes' . DS . 'framework.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_SITE . DS . 'libraries' . DS . 'joomla' . DS . 'factory.php' );


//Import filesystem libraries. Perhaps not necessary, but does not hurt

jimport('joomla.filesystem.path');
jimport('joomla.filesystem.file');
jimport('joomla.filesystem.folder');
jimport('joomla.user.user');



//First we set up parameters
$searchpath = JPATH_BASE . DS . "upload";





//Then we create the subfolder called png
if ( !JFolder::create($searchpath . DS ."Images") ) {
   //Throw error message and stop script
}

//Now we read all png files and put them in an array.
$png_files = JFolder::files($searchpath,'.png');

//Now we need some stuff from the JFile:: class to move all files into the new folder
foreach ($png_files as $file) {
   JFile::move($searchpath. DS . ".png" . $file, $searchpath . DS. "Images" . $file);
}

//Lastly, we are moving the complete subdir to the root of the component.
if (JFolder::move($searchpath . DS. "Images",JPATH_COMPONENT) ) {
   //Redirect with perhaps a happy message
} else {
   //Throw an error

            }
}


?>
```

Only error i get is Notice: Use of undefined constant JPATH_COMPONENT - assumed 'JPATH_COMPONENT' in /upload.php on line 70. But doesn't stop it working, am so close on this any help is greatly appreciated. I want to know where its taking the image, i think i have worked out the "DS" now.

Thanks

Comment: `DS` is a directory separator, meaning `/`. It is not a space. You have created a class with a function but are not calling it. This is the problem with copying and pasting code from somewhere on the internet when you do not understand what it does. You also need to realise that as you want to detect uploads via FTP, you will need to create a cron job to execute your PHP file. PHP cannot detect uploads via FTP, only files that are within a directory

Comment: Thanks, yes i understand about setting cronjob to execute the php file just want to sort php file first before setting that up, i'm in testing at the moment to see what is best to sort this out. Thanks for the help tho

Comment: Ok i'll take one bit at a time, slightly changed done some research: The 

<?php

include(JPATH_BASE.'libraries/loader.php'); - Calling in the loader so that i can load the jimport to import the libraries. 

Then: 

//Import filesystem libraries. Perhaps not necessary, but does not hurt

jimport('joomla.filesystem.path');
jimport('joomla.filesystem.file');
jimport('joomla.filesystem.folder');

I then get the error from that saying: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'jimport' (T_STRING).

What does that mean?

Comment: Assuming this is an external PHP file (not part of a Joomla extension), you cannot use Joomla code unless you import the Joomla framework.

Comment: Have updated code in main text above any ideas?

Comment: As mentioned before, `DS` is a separator, not a space, therefore remove it where used before ".png". What is `Simpson`? And you need to remove the `$` from `$JPATH_COMPONENT` as this is a constant, not a variable.

Comment: updated code above any ideas. Thanks alot you have really helped me

Comment: The simpson is what i thought was the folder it was creating. I have removed $ as well. Not wanting to transfer file anyideas?

Comment: You still have `.DS.` before `".png"`. I've told you already that `.DS.` is a directory separator, not a space, there for `.DS.".png"` will result in `/.png` which is not correct. There are also come cases where you need to change `"png"` to `".png"`

Comment: Ok thanks alot, so i have moved things to a better server but since i havethe php wont run in my upload folder instead i get this error message: Error displaying the error page: Application Instantiation Error: Application Instantiation Error. Doing some research they said check your db  connection but it is correct. However the odd thing is if i move the php to say the root or modules folder it doesn't flag up error, do you know a way round this?

Comment: And my directory structure has changed to:
httpdocs/php/ - Joomla Files
httpdocs/php/upload - Where php file is

Comment: Have worked it out thanks for the help :)

Comment: Please post your answer and mark it as accepted to people know you've solved it

Comment: I'm missing just one part, thats to read the file name so the filename looks like this "23-10-14 Joe235664b" is there a bit of code or change a bit of code so that it ignores the date but read after the space, the "Joe235664b" and create the folder if it doesn't exist "Joe235664b" and place whatever files that have  "Joe235664b" into that new folder?

Comment: Google >> PHP regular expressions. You will need to use this to strip the date

Comment: Thought i had it working because it created the folder, moved the directory into the component section where i place my code. So my code is in:
Administrator/components/com_upload - upload.php 

When i run it, it create the folder Images in the: root/upload, but does not put the png file i have in the upload into the Images folder, where abouts does it take it? I have update the code above. I think i have sorted the DS on there. Any help is appreciated, i'm so close on this.